# Recursive function to calculate sum of all numbers from 1 to n?

Tags: scheme, racket

The problem I'm trying to solve:

```
Write a Scheme function called "my-sum" which takes a  
nonnegative number n and outputs the value
1+2+ .. +n
Your solution should use recursion.
```

I've got the general function defined... and I know how I would do this in C++ without recursion. But I'm having a hard time deciding how to go about this with Scheme.

What I've got so far:

```
(define my-sum
(lambda (x)
  (+ x (- x 1))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a purely recursive solution:

```
(define (my-sum x)
  (if (zero? x)
      0
      (+ x (my-sum (- x 1)))))
```

Unfortunately, that's not tail recursive. Here's a version that is tail recursive:

```
(define (my-sum x sum)
  (if (zero? x)
      sum
      (my-sum (- x 1) (+ x sum))))
```

You can call it like this:

```
(my-sum x 0)
```

Here, `sum` is the accumulator.

Your second answer does the same thing, using an internal helper function that is tail recursive, providing the initial value to the accumulator in the initial call to the internal helper function.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (my-sum n)
  (define (my-sum-helper n m)
     (if (= 0 n)
        m
        (my-sum-helper (- n 1) (+ n m))))
  (my-sum-helper n 0))
```

Comment: Please describe your solution.

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.

Comment: @soegaard fair enough, I was only looking at it from review - either way it's better to include some explanation for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

The exercise is to sum the numbers from 1 to n using a recursive function.

This is an exercise from the book SICP. Solutions to the exercises are available from many sources. In this case "Bill the Lizard" gives a very good explanation:

https://billthelizard.blogspot.com/2010/04/sicp-exercise-130-iterative-sums.html

Note that in "real" Racket, one would just write:

```
(for/sum ([x (in-range 1 (+ n 1))])   ; let x run through 1, 2, ... n
   x)                                 ; add x to the running sum
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use 'named let' here for an easy to understand function that defines and applies recursion immediately:

```
(define (mysum n)
  (let loop ((m 0)
             (s 0))
    (cond
      [(> m n) s]
      [else (loop (add1 m) 
                  (+ s m))])))
```

The keyword 'else' can be omitted here. Code using 'if' can also be used here instead of 'cond' since there are only 2 conditions.